# How can I disable the jtag in atmega 32 using serial programmer?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, jtag

How can I disable the JTAG in the ATmega32 using a serial programmer?

Answer (score 4):

(from http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=53097&start=0)

```
avrdude -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m
```

Or:

```
ldi   temp,0x80
out   mcucsr,temp      ;JTAG
out   mcucsr,temp      ;disabled
```

(I have not tested either of these as I have no ATmega32. Messing with AVR fuses can potentially brick your chip unless you  have a high voltage/parallel programmer, caveat emptor...)

Answer (score 1):

You disable the JTag by setting the fuses. You can use the [AVR Fuse Calculator](http://palmavr.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/fc.cgi).