# ATmega32A pins output issues

Tags: microcontroller, led, atmega, output

I’ve an issue with my [ATmega32A](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/atmega32a) in some of PORTC pins.

I’m trying to control some LEDs using MCU but I faced an issue with PINC2,3,4,5 as shown in picture bellow.

*Off state (LED num 3,4,5,6 from the bottom):*
[image]

*On state:*
[image]

*My code:*
[image]

*And here is my schematic:*
[image]

[image]

I measured the output voltage in those pins using voltmeter.

With LEDs connected:

- On state: 2.6 V
- Off state: 2.9 V

Without the LEDs:

- On state: 4 V
- Off state: 5 V

Only one pin PINC4:

- With LEDs connected: 1 V
- Without the LEDs: 2 V

I don’t know what’s going on. Can anyone explain what’s happening?

Answer (score 1):

By default, on these pins on PORTC the JTAG interface is enabled. So, to get access to PORTC you need to disable the JTAG interface by setting the **Fuse High Byte** to **0xD9**.

[How can I disable the jtag in atmega 32 using serial programmer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/how-can-i-disable-the-jtag-in-atmega-32-using-serial-programmer)

Or try to use this code to disable JTAG in your software:

```c
/*disable JTAG*/
MCUCSR |= (1 << JTD); 
MCUCSR |= (1 << JTD);
```

Reference: [ATmega32A Data Sheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega32A-DataSheet-Complete-DS40002072A.pdf)
[image]